# Cannot open file libcpmtd.lib

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

[image]
I have selected Multi-threaded Debug to make my program portable on windows, however as soon as I select it this error comes up: cannot open file 'libcpmtd.lib'

[image]

This is my General page in the settings

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253383/cannot-open-file-dxguid-lib?rq=1

Comment: this answer is irrelevant, that person is using DirectX, which isn't a built-in lib like libcpmtd

Comment: What Visual Studio and MSVC version?

Comment: i have visual studio 2017, where do i find my msvc version?

Comment: Pls show the VC++ Directories and C/C++ General settings for the Active configuration.

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.2 is my current build.  I have no clue about my MSVC

Comment: fyi i found my msvc version, it is 14.10.25017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by upgrading my Visual Studio to the newest version.